# question about possibility of 3 given functions of lengths of a triangle, themselves forming a triangle.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

x = f(a,b,c),
y = g(a,b,c), and z = h(a,b,c)

if a,b,c are sides of a triangle, then x,y,z are also sides of a triangle.

How can you write sets of functions f,g and h?

Comment: Do you mean, conditions on $x,y,z$?  In any case, please edit for context.  What is the source of this problem?  What have you tried?  It's easy to produce examples where $p,q,r$ *do* make a triangle...what are some examples in which it doesn't?  Can you say something about those?

Comment: Well, I suggest starting with examples. Find some examples in which you fail to get a triangle, try to generalize those.

Comment: x=y=z=1, can be.  If they are, p, q and r will be equal and hence form  an equilateral triangle.

Comment: In fact, x, y,z can be equal to any number.  Then p,q and r will form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: As suggested in the context of another question, posted the same question in mathematics educators exchange also.